# TX-row lock contention : Inserting Duplicate values for Unique Key

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, locking, jobs

We are getting a **TX-row lock contention** error while trying to insert data

It happens while running a job which processes an xml with almost 10000 records, inserting the data into a table

We are having a unique key constraint on one of the columns in the table, and in the request we are getting duplicate values. This is causing the locks and thereby the job is taking more time.

We are using hibernate and spring. The DAO method we use is hibernate template's 'save' annotated with Spring Transaction Manager's @Transactional

Any suggestions please?

Comment: Do you have multiple processes running the insertions?

Comment: @DavidAldridge No just one

Comment: Do you know what mode the enqueues are? Typically 4 or 6. These TX enqueues occur between two sessions, not on a single session (well, very rarely)

Comment: `while running a job` - please post job code

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear whether you're getting locking problems or errors.

"TX-row lock contention" is an event indicating that two sessions are trying to insert the same value into a primary or unique constraint column set -- an error is not raised until the first one commits, then the second one gets the error. So you definitely have multiple sessions inserting rows. If you just had one session then you'd receive the error immediately, with no "TX-row lock contention" event being raised.

Suggestions:

1. Insert into a temporary table without the constraint, then load to the real table using logic that eliminates the duplicates
2. Eliminate the duplicates as part of the read of the XML.
3. Use Oracle's error logging syntax -- example here. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9014.htm#SQLRF55004